# Fading a Line Exponentially

Tags: python, math, graphics

I'd like to fade the values of a line on the Y axis using a gradient that I can control.

[image: Fade]

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying right now.

```py
y_values = [1,1,1,1,1,1]

for i, y in enumerate(y_values): #i is the index, y is the individual y value
    perc = i/(len(y_values)-1) #progress the fade by the percentage of the index divided by the total values
    amt = y * perc #y is the target amount to decrease multiplied by index percentage
    y -= amt
    print(i,y)
```

This code produces this:

```
1.0
0.8
0.6
0.4
0.2
0.0
```

It's creating a linear fade, but how do I increase the fade with an exponential fade like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ar0h6g6aag)?

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2):

To make exponential fading, you have to provide two coefficients to provide initial factor `1.0` at the start value `x1` and desired final factor `k` at the end of interval `x2`

```
y = y * f(x)
f(x) = A * exp(-B * x)
```

So

```
f(x1) = 1 = A * exp(B * x1)
f(x2) = k = A * exp(B * x2)
```

divide the second by the first

```
k = exp(B * (x2 - x1))
ln(k) = B * (x2 - x1)
```

so

```
B = ln(k) / (x2 - x1)
A = exp(B * x1)
```

Example for x1 = 0, x2 = 60, k = 0.01

```
B = -4.6/60= -0.076
A = 1
f(x) = exp(-0.076*x)
f(30) = exp(-0.076*20) = 0.1
```

Python example:

```
import math

def calcfading(x1, x2, ratio):
    B = math.log(ratio) / (x2 - x1)
    A = math.exp(B * x1)
    return A, B

def coef(x, fade):
    return fade[0]*math.exp(x*fade[1])

cosine = [[x, math.cos(x)] for x in range(0, 11)]
print(cosine)
print()
fade = calcfading(0, 10, 0.01)
expcosine = [[s[0], coef(s[0], fade)*s[1]] for s in cosine]
print(expcosine)
```

Comment: Hi MBo, thank you very much for the reply! I'm sorry but my math skills aren't enough to understand how to convert this into Python. I have simplified my code example in my original post. Would you help me understand what `A`, `B`, `x1`, `k`, and `x2` from your code would be in my original code? Also, it seems like you're solving the equation with multiple = in a line which has confused me as I'm trying to understand how to set up functions and variable assignments. Any clarification on your post would be very greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `multiple = in a line` just shows name and value. Python code added